# add select option to alert js

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know if it is possible to make an alert or something like it in js with select options like html. I want to display select options on a pop-up box and switch the selected option, make an event on it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about native alert or prompt, you won't be able to change the content (other than the text it self of course).

You need external libraries like:

- https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/
- http://alertifyjs.com/examples.html

**Update**
As @jhpratt said,  you can use native `<dialog>` element, [which is not supported in multiple browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog) [but there's a polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill).

[Here's a full example.](https://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/)

Comment: Note that `<dialog>` is supported natively in Chrome, and is the intended replacement to libraries like this. A polyfill exists for other browsers.